# Compilation fail with pstool: \begin{document} wrapped in \makeatletter \makeatother

Tags: beamer, errors, pdftex

I'm trying to create a presentation with LaTeX `beamer` using `pstool`, and since updating my system to Ubuntu 13.10 (pstool 1.5a, TeX Live 2013) the compilation of the pstool auxiliary TeX files (*-pstool.tex) fails, with the following message in the log:

```
! Improper \spacefactor.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.19 \immediate \write \@
                         mainaux {\@percentchar <*PSTOOLLABELS>}
```

I could trace the problem to the following section in the created files:

```
\makeatletter 
\def \thepage {\csname @arabic\endcsname \c@page }
\setcounter {page}{15}
\@input {presentation.oldaux}

\begin {document}
\immediate \write \@mainaux {\@percentchar <*PSTOOLLABELS>}
\makeatother 
\centering \null \vfill
```

If I either move the `\begin{document}` below the `\makeatother` or add another `\makeatletter` right after it, I can manually compile the auxiliary file (latex, dvipdf), but of course this is not a solution. Apparently, `\begin{document}` cancels the `\makeatletter`. The problem is that the problematic section is automatically generated by pstool, and manually changing it for each and every EPS graphic is hardly feasible. Any ideas how I can work around this problem?

**Edit:** Here is a complete example of the TeX file using `pstool`. The errors occur during the compilation of the auxiliary file created by `pstool`, `test-pstool.tex` in this case. The EPS file `test.eps` contains only a box with the label "test".

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\EndPreamble

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{center}
      \pstool[width=0.5\textwidth]{test}{
        \psfrag{test}[][]{Test}
      }
      \caption{Test}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\makeatother` before `\begin{document}` and `\makeatletter` before `\immediate\write`.

Comment: The problem is that this is an auxiliary file that is recreated every time `pstool` processes the EPS image, so that change would be overwritten.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of a file producing the issue? Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Damn — I was aware of this problem and had fixed it in March, but uploading to CTAN fell off my todo list. On its way now…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, `\begin{document}` resets the category code of `@` doing `\makeatother`, but only in `beamer`, not in the standard classes. This is probably why the problem went unnoticed till now.

It's just a matter of adding `\makeatletter` in the macro the package uses for writing the auxiliary file (I'd add also `\makeatother` before, just by symmetry). I'm pretty sure the change will be made if the author is made aware of the problem.

As a temporary workaround you can patch the relevant macro either by copying it in your preamble and adding the missing bits:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pstool@write@processfile#1#2#3{%
  \immediate\openout\pstool@out #2\pstool@suffix.tex\relax
  [...]
% And the document body to place the graphic on a page of its own:
    \noexpand\@input{\jobname.oldaux}^^J^^J%
    \noexpand\makeatother^^J^^J% <---- ADDED
    \noexpand\begin{document}^^J%
    \noexpand\makeatletter^^J%   <---- ADDED
    \unexpanded{\immediate\write\@mainaux}{\pstool@auxmarker*}^^J%
    \noexpand\makeatother^^J%
  [...]
  \immediate\closeout\pstool@out
}
\makeatother
```

where `[...]` denotes the (long) parts that should be unmodified.

A simpler strategy is patching the macro. Unfortunately, patching the macro with `etoolbox` can't be done because it contains `^^J`. But you can with `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\EndPreamble

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\pstool@write@processfile
 {\noexpand\begin{document}}
 {\noexpand\makeatother^^J^^J%
  \noexpand\begin{document}^^J%
  \noexpand\makeatletter}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\pstool[width=0.5\textwidth]{test}{
  \psfrag{test}[][]{Test}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm not expert with `pstool`, so I put `\EndPreamble` where it seemed better.

Comment: Thank you, with one little edit (pending for peer review right now) the regexpatch solution works. :-)

Comment: With version 1.5b of `pstool.sty` (2013/03/11) the problem seems to have been solved.