# How to use pstool and babelbib in the same document?

Tags: languages, babel, eps

I'm trying to use the `pstool` package and the `babelbib` package in my document. I couldn't manage to process an `.eps` image, when one of the languages loaded by `babel` is `english`. Here's an example, with an arbitrary eps-image, that doesn't work on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{pic}
\end{document}
```

It works fine when either

- the `babelbib` package is removed,
- the `\usepackage{babelbib}` is moved below the `\EndPreamble` or
- `babel` is loaded with a different language, like `ngerman`.

Hence the `--shell-escape` should be set up properly. But these work-arounds either change the document or require a major alteration of the preamble. Is there another way to get this to work?

Here's the first error from the `.log` of the auto-generated `.tex`-File:

```
! Improper \spacefactor.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.17 \immediate \write \@
                         mainaux {\@percentchar <*PSTOOLLABELS>}
You can refer to \spacefactor only in horizontal mode;
you can refer to \prevdepth only in vertical mode; and
neither of these is meaningful inside \write. So
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.
```

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9:

- `babel`-Version: v3.8m
- `pstool`-Version: v1.5a
- `babelbib`-Version: v1.31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.5b of `pstool` should have fixed the problem, which has a very similar cause as the issue described in [Compilation fail with pstool: \begin{document} wrapped in \makeatletter \makeatother](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141036/compilation-fail-with-pstool-begindocument-wrapped-in-makeatletter-makeato)

Update the package and all should go well.